# Sending an executable C program to someone

Tags: c

I was just thinking about sending an executable fun C program (which asks for a name and prints funny stuff like `printf("What a lovely name you have, %s!\n", name);`) to a friend and I had an idea of this but I wonder if this is even possible.
Is there any way I can see their input?
For example, a friend opens the program in his/her computer and enters his/her name in it, is there a way I can receive that input information? I am not trying to hack or do bad things I am just curious. Or maybe I guess this is beyond the scope of C?

Comment: You can have your program send their input via socket (you will probably use HTTP(S) or e-mail, etc.)

Comment: The easiest way to see their input is to start a zoom session.

Comment: thanks @MikeCAT that's a good idea.

Comment: hahaha a Zoom session sounds fun xD This is what we do every day anyway

Comment: Sounds like you want to learn about client-server architecture.

Comment: *"I am not trying to hack or do bad things"* Maybe you're not trying to do bad things, but it's definitely a hack ;)

Comment: If the recipient is even slightly computer-literate, they will not run your app, (except maybe if they have a virtual machine they can write off).

Comment: I would rather have somebody borrow my toothbrush than let them run an executable on my computer :)

Comment: I would recommend you python for socket programming.
https://realpython.com/python-sockets/

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is beyond the scope of C. The language proper has no notions of its environment apart from memory. Standard C comes with a **standard library** though which allows a standardized interaction with a somewhat wider environment; this standardization is one reason for C's success story when it took off.

The most important part of this virtual "standard library environment" is the notion of a data source and/or sink represented by a FILE structure. On such a "stream" a limited set of actions can be performed (namely opening, potentially with some name, reading/writing and read/write positioning).

These C standard library functions (fopen, fread, frwite etc.) use underlying operating system facilities, but these are (deliberately) outside the language's or the standard library's scope.

For completeness: A widely available, standardized operating system interface is [Posix](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/). Posix basically standardizes Unix facilities but is available on other platforms as well (cygwin is an example). Posix integrates well with C, which was co-developed with Unix and shares its data types and philosophy. In many (most?) C implementations some subset of Posix functions is available (e.g. open, read/write).

Posix standardizes Unix' I/O concept of byte streams identified by file descriptors, simple numbers. These *can* be obtained by an `open()` command on a file system "file" (which is an abstract concept on Unix/Posix in the first place) but can as well directly identify other communication channels like pipes or sockets. This is possible because the standardized interface on "file" descriptors is very small; it is basically limited to unformatted I/O and positioning (and any of these may not work on a given descriptor). The physical nature of these byte streams is essentially irrelevant for this core functionality. In your case, you would want to use internet sockets for a connection between the two computers, for example established by  your computer opening a *listening* (server) socket and the remote computer connecting to it as a client. But none of this is known to C or its standard library, and although sockets are probably the most common way to communicate between computers there are many other ways (e.g. you could establish a "direct link" through a telephone "line").